# Mac OS X: Can I write application files within the app bundle?

Tags: macos, file, tcl, tk-toolkit

- The application will be located in /Applications.
- The application will be downloaded via a web browser and not via the App Store.
- The language being used is Tcl/Tk.

A. Will this work on all versions of OS X 10.5 or higher?

B. Is there a better place to store application files?

Comment: It's a very bad idea; first because the app might be on a read-only device (how do you guarantee it's in /Applications?) and second because it cannot possibly work for multiple users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`~/Library/Application Support` is a way [better place](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) to store your files:

> Use this directory to store all app data files except those associated
>   with the user’s documents. For example, you might use this directory
>   to store app-created data files, configuration files, templates, or
>   other fixed or modifiable resources that are managed by the app. An
>   app might use this directory to store a modifiable copy of resources
>   contained initially in the app’s bundle. A game might use this
>   directory to store new levels purchased by the user and downloaded
>   from a server.

Answer (score 2):

A. No, generally you should not alter the application bundle once installed.  You will very likely encounter permissions or code signing issues if you do.

B. `~/Library/Application Support/MyApp/`

Comment: No code-signing issues here; explicitly not delivered via App Store according to questioner…

Comment: @DonalFellows You can deliver code-signed apps not via the App Store.